# Where should I install seafile-server: /opt or /home?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure, fhs

Reading [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) I was considering those directories:

- `/opt`: Optional application software packages.
- `/home`: Users' home directories, containing saved files, personal settings, etc.

I was more inclined to use `/opt` but many tutorials use `/home` (e.g. [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Seafile))

#### Question

- Where should I install seafile-server: `/opt` or `/home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `/home` is generally used for end users' home directories, it is not a good practice to mount general use filesystems in `/home`, as it may lead to a confusion later on with other sysadmins, whom, one day, will take over this system from you upon your departure for greener pastures.

I am not familiar with seafile-server, but assuming it is a 3rd party application and its related directory tree, then it is fine to mount it under `/opt`.

Having said all of this, mounting a directory on either `/home` or `/opt`, technically has no difference. Just make sure you are not doing nested mounts, i.e., mounting a filesystem over another filesystem. Even though this is technically possible, it lends itself to problems in the future, if the higher level filesystem decides to go bust one day. I know it is not your question, but just make sure, wherever you are mounting this filesystem under, is not a mounted filesystem, but a plain directory on root filesystem (i.e., under "/").